# CQRS and calculations

Tags: architecture, cqrs

I am currently working on some proof-of-concept code that follows the CQRS pattern and I cannot find a satisfactory solution to a problem I [think I] have.

The system calculates the impact of market changes against a given portfolio based on specific scenarios.

Portfolios can contain from one to several hundreds of holdings and market scenarios are pre-defined or defined on the fly by the user for a specific request.

In its simplest form the solution to this problem would be a service that returns some values given the input, but in the CQRS case it seems to me that the part that performs the calculation (domain) should not be called by the part that actually returns the data (query).

Considering that a system such as this would easily have several portfolios and that the number of scenarios can also be quite high, I don't think it would make sense to store the results of the calculations.

Anyone has a solution to this issue or can point me in the direction of an article that solves a problem similar to this one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CQRS does not say that you should pre-calculate everything in the write side. When the state of the system changes through a command, events are created and projections listen to these events and create a model that can be used for querying. What this model looks like and what it is used for is up to you. You could even create a projection of a complete 3rd normal form database representation of your system if you want to.

If it would be more practical for you to do these calculations on the read side then I see no problem with doing that, just as long as it is ok to lose the result of the calculations.

Comment: +1.  Yes, the read model could be a complete 3rd normal form database, a OLAP cube, a data warehouse, an Excel file--anything, and it can all be precalculated, projected on demand, or anywhere in between.

Comment: so what you are suggesting is in line with @BorisEegerink that basically I would have two domain models. One suited for writing and the other suited for retrieving data?

Comment: Precalculating the results looks like a good idea, if the amount of combinations are manageable?

Comment: @mhttk - Yes, I think that it is a good idea. I agree with Boris Eetgerinks answer.

Answer (score 6):

To me the whole point of CQRS is creating two domain models. One optimized for updating data with commands and one optimized for reading data with queries. A query should never visibly alter the system. Storing the result of calculations in a cache of sorts is an implementation detail of the query domain model. As long as the cache is invalidated in time, that is, the query side is eventually consistent with the command side, you're fine. You should of course control how much 'eventually' is acceptable in the application.

When you calculate the impact of market changes against a portfolio you are executing queries against the query domain model. I don't see a problem with creating query types for the scenarios you're interested in.

So, in conclusion, I don't think you have a problem. Remember that you can (shoud?!) hide the complexity of the calculations in the query handlers and/or the query domain model.

Comment: I like your take on this. I think that when you see it like this, the roles between write model and read model in the app are clarified.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems to be suggesting that there can be business logic on the read-side, i.e. as a part of the read-side domain model. I like this approach more than the suggestion that the read-side is just about different presentations / views of the read state (e.g.denormalised).

Comment: This brings up another question though.  Can the read-side publish events (based on properties it has determined from events received)?  Other (sub)systems may like to know about changes to these properties without having to query (poll) the read-side.

Answer (score 3):

IMHO calculations are only required in write model if results of those calculations are needed to hold invariants. No more, no less.

Lets use example of (very simplified) banking domain:
If your invariants state that you cant withdraw more money than you have on an account than you should calculate balance (which is sum of withdrawals and deposits on that account) and maybe store it (if you have some kind of aggregate) to be able to check if withdrawal amount is more than that actual balance, but if your system has no such invariants then calculations are unnecessary and balance quite possibly should only be calculated on the read side for your system clients.

It also occurred to me that you might actually ask if you can use read side for those calculations (if they are computational heavy) - that depends. 
Most will say, that you should not use read side on write side, but even Greg Young once said that sometimes it is acceptable. 
Just remember that using read side on write side might make your model inconsistent as read side data might be out of date.

Comment: As above, can the read-side publish events (based on properties it has calculated from events received)? For example, if the balance is calculated on the read-side (since it is not needed for an invariant on the write-side) can the read-side publish an event with the new balance. 
 Other (sub)systems may like to know about changes to these properties without having to query (poll) the read-side.  How would the read-side publishing events work when the read-side model needed to be rebuilt?  It could stop publishing events but how would it know when to start publishing events again?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using CQRS because you need massive scalability, and scalability revolves around reading the results of those calculations, you will want to store those results pre-calculated in your read models.

If scale/performance is not a major concern, then I see no problem with calculating on the fly.

Either way, it sounds like the calculators/calculations themselves are part of the read model, and not the domain model.  It sounds like the command/write side would contain a collection of inputs, and those would be projected onto outputs by your calculators/calculations.